# Is there a way to resize python list using Python-C API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-c-api

My C-application is loading the python interpreter dll and calling the function `list = PyList_New(len)` to create a new python list of 'len' size. 

Two questions: 
1. What happens if I call `PyList_Append(list, item)` more than `len` times? I assume it should throw an exception. Is my understanding correct?

2. More importantly, my second question is whether there is a way to resize the list? I looked at the C APIs at: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_SetItem, but could not find such an API. Any suggestions/comments/workaround?

The context of my question is that I need to create the list much earlier than when the list items and the count of them is known.

Answer (score 0):

`PyList_New` creates a list filled with `NULL` pointers. You're supposed to set all of those pointers using `PyList_SetItem` before sending the list back to Python or calling any Python functions on it.

`PyList_Append` (and `PyList_Insert`) are really just equivalent to calling `somelist.append` (and `somelist.insert`) from Python. They resize the list for you. I'm not 100% sure if they account any `NULL` elements, so it's probably best not to call them on a list that you've made from `PyList_New` and that you haven't completely filled yet.  What you're doing (allocating a list with some `NULL` pointers then appending it) is definitely wrong since the `NULL` pointers are never filled in. Instead you should just be using  `PyList_Append` and `PyList_Insert` on a list built from empty. You could also call `list.extend` to add multiple elements to the list at once - there is no direct access to that through the C API but you can call it through `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs` or similar.

Internally the list allocates more space than it needs to it only has to reallocate occasionally. There's no way for you to control this.